# How to import a range, based on a selection from drop-down list?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to figure out a way to import a range/array based on a selection made in another sheet's column.

To explain better, I have constructed the following example--

*spreadsheet:* https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HVv_Bfy7hBaATxFI1WjE1T-nn8uYohyPYvKWJKWoSKM/edit?usp=sharing

Here, I have 5 sheets--

1. Categories: Types of ingredients
2. Ingredients: All ingredients & price of each unit
3. Recipes: Recipes of multiple preparations (number & price of ingredients). Recipes of each preparation is always fixed.
4. Tender 1 (Birthday party): A list of preparations & quantities of preparations ordered.
5. Tender 2 (Promotion party): Another similar list.

Suppose, I have a catering business. My company receives a request to cater to a birthday party, and order 5 apple pies, 4 mixed-fruit juice & 2 broccoli soup.
Recipes of apple pie, juice & soup are already tabulated in "recipes" sheet.
I want the Tenders sheets to be such, that I only have to select the name of the preparations(pie/soup/juice) ordered from a drop-down & quantity of each. Example, in tender 1 sheet, if I choose "apple pie", the red highlighted range should appear automatically. If I enter quantity "5", the prices should be calculated accordingly.

Is there a way that this can be achieved?

Many thanks for reading this far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution using Google Sheets formula

You can use the QUERY formula to have the red highlighted range appear automatically.
For that, you need to modify your recipies tab a bit to look like this i.e. each row needs to have the preparation identifier.

[image]

Secondly, use the below formula in D5, D9 and D17 of Tender1 sheet. First, clear the content in range D5:F18 otherwise the formulas will return an error.

```
=QUERY(recipes!A2:D, "SELECT B,C,D WHERE A = '"&$B5&"'")
```

Change the B5 in above query to B9 and B17 accordingly.

For getting the prices based on quantity, you can simple use the MULTIPLY formula as the base prices are already fetched using the query above.

Note: The same can be easily achieved using Apps Script as well if needed. This solution is using Sheets formula.

### Solution using Apps Script

Below is the code. I've tested it in this spreadsheet, just for reference:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h9unXlOCk9aNQXYoM-wxI2a5p9WlMPRmSFWD5zp572Y/edit

You can tweak it a little further if any additional requirement.

This function will run whenever some one changes the dropdown values.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var recipesSheet = ss.getSheetByName('recipes');
  if (sheet.getName() == "tender 1" && e.range.columnStart == 2) {
    if (e.range.rowStart == 5 || e.range.rowStart == 9 || e.range.rowStart == 15) {

      // Get row num of the selected dropdown value in recipes tab.
      var valInDropdown = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).getValue();
      var recipePreparations = recipesSheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
      var rowNumsOfSelectedValue = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < recipePreparations.length; i++) {
        if (valInDropdown == recipePreparations[i]) rowNumsOfSelectedValue.push(i + 2);
      }

      var valuesToCopy = recipesSheet.getRange(rowNumsOfSelectedValue[0], 2, rowNumsOfSelectedValue.length, 3).getValues();
      sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4, 4, 3).clearContent();
      console.log('e.range.rowStart ' + e.range.rowStart + ' rowNumsOfSelectedValue.length ' + rowNumsOfSelectedValue.length);
      sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 4, rowNumsOfSelectedValue.length, 3).setValues(valuesToCopy);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! However, I think apps script would be a lot easier for me to implement on this sheet, as multiple laymen will be accessing it & might keep deleting the formula. Could you kindly help me out with the apps script solution that you mentioned in your note?

Comment: Of course! Give me some time. I'll update the answer to include Apps Script solution as well.

Comment: Done, updated the answer with apps script code.